# Cron job reboot without sudo

Tags: python, cron, geckodriver

Is there a way to give user crontab permission to use reboot command?

I want crontab to activate a python script that uses geckodriver and then reboots the device when the script finishes. The problem currently is that geckodriver won't run as root and my non-root crontab gives the error below when the script tries to use reboot command:

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required. 
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to start reboot.target:Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.
```

If it's not possible to give non-root cron job permission to reboot, is there some other handy way to circumvent the problem? I guess one solution could be to separate the reboot part of the script as second script and include that in root crontab to be ran after the first script.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: why sudo is not an option

Comment: You can use sudo with a configuration that would allow a certain user to run certain commands w/o requiring an interactive (or any) authentication. Read about the `sudoers` file and `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: Adrian: If I run the script with sudo, geckodriver won't run. It seems to be an intentional feature from what I read.

Comment: @Milkymilk, you don't have to run the script with sudo, only the reboot command from within the script (after correct suders config).

Comment: @marekful, that would very well I think! How would that work within the script? Currently my reboot command in the script is: "os.system('systemctl reboot -i')"